# How to detach from process, so that it can be traced by another process?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

Program steps:

1. Create child process by fork and call execv inside it
2. Ptrace attach to child process
3. Do something with ptrace
4. Detach from child
5. execute gdb -p child_pid

But when gdb starts, it writes that child process is already tracked.
How to detach from traced process, so that it can be traced by another process?

Code that do things above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

#define Error(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(0); } while(0)
#define PTRACE_E(req, pid, addr, data) \
    do { \
        if(ptrace(req, pid, addr, data) < 0) { \
            perror(#req); \
            exit(0); \
        } \
    } while(0)
#define BUF_SIZE 16

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pid_t pid;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    int status;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <executable> [ARGS]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        Error("fork");
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        if(execv(argv[1], &argv[1]) < 0)
            Error("execv");
    }

    PTRACE_E(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);

    while(wait(&status) && !WIFEXITED(status)) {
        PTRACE_E(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);

        if(regs.orig_eax == 26 && regs.ebx == PTRACE_TRACEME) {
            regs.eax = 0;

            PTRACE_E(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);
            break;
        }

        PTRACE_E(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }

    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);

    snprintf(buf, BUF_SIZE, "%d", pid);
    execl("/usr/bin/gdb", "/usr/bin/gdb", "-p", buf, NULL);
}
```

Comment: `ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, sig)` ?

Comment: @oakad I used ptrace_detach, but it doesn't work, so I asked this question

Comment: @Cyberfined can you add the #includes to the top of the example?

Comment: @jamieguinan Yes, it's done.

Comment: Trying to repeat your test case here. What is your subcommand, and how does it set eax and ebx?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to check the return value of `ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH,...)`?

Comment: Also, it looks to me like your `while` loop will only finish when the process has exited?  How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @jamieguinan Test: `./tracer subcommand`. Output: warning: process 9335 is already traced by process 9334. process 9335 is a zombie - the process has already terminated. ptrace operation not permitted. Subcommand is any program which uses PTRACE_TRACEME anti-debugging method. For example `if(ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) < 0) exit(0);`. Hence eax is set to 26, which means ptrace syscall on x86, ebx is set to 0, which means PTRACE_TRACEME.

Comment: @NateEldredge It continue executes program until ptrace_traceme syscall, if it happens, set eax to 0 which means success, hence ptrace anti-debugging method stops working

Comment: @NateEldredge Probably you're right, but in my case ptrace_detach always returns success

Comment: Your `if(regs.orig_eax == 26 ...` test is done on system call entry, and your `regs.eax = 0;` just changes -38 to 0. Then you break. In order to affect the system call's return value, you need to set eax when ptrace stops on system call exit. When your parent detaches, the child is resumed, its TRACEME succeeds, making the parent the tracer again.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I do this by `PTRACE_E(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to note here is that the PTRACE_SYSCALL request will make the target process stop **at entry to** or exit from a system call. The [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) says

> Syscall-enter-stop and syscall-exit-stop are indistinguishable from
>   each other by the tracer.  The tracer needs to keep track of the
>   sequence of ptrace-stops in order to not misinterpret syscall-enter-stop
>   as syscall-exit-stop or vice versa.

If you use ptrace to change the target's register values, you'll change the system call arguments that the kernel will see, or the return value that the user process will see, depending on whether you do it at syscall-enter-stop or syscall-exit-stop.

Your code here is run at syscall-enter-stop:

```
if (regs.orig_eax == 26 && regs.ebx == PTRACE_TRACEME) {
    regs.eax = 0;
    PTRACE_E(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);
    break;
}
```

It changes eax (which is -38 on entry to a system call) to 0. Since your intent was to change the return code from the target's PTRACE_TRACEME request from -1 to 0, you'll need to do PTRACE_SYSCALL one more time, so that the target will stop at syscall-exit-stop, before running the above code.

Currently, your code breaks out of the loop after the PTRACE_SETREGS request, and then does

```
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
```

which will detach from the target and continue it. The (now ex-)target completes its PTRACE_TRACEME request, which succeeds, making its parent the tracer once again.

```
execl("/usr/bin/gdb", "/usr/bin/gdb", "-p", buf, NULL);
```

Gdb will give a warning message, because it is, unexpectedly, already the tracer for the target.